# Cypress selectFile without an input element in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

When the upload button is clicked, the file browser opens using the below method. As far as I'm aware, there is no element added to the DOM unless you explicitly append it to a DOM element.

```js
const inputEl = document.createElement("input");
inputEl.type = "file";
inputEl.multiple = true;
inputEl.click();
inputEl.onchange = (e) => { ... }
```

Is it possible to select a file in Cypress using this method? `selectFile` requires the `input` element to be in DOM and chained off it. Otherwise, I'd have to use hidden input elements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. You can't do it in Cypress. I used an environment variable "DEVELOPMENT=1" to append the input element to the DOM, but only during testing.

```js
const inputEl = document.createElement("input");
if (process.env.DEVELOPMENT) {
    document.getElementById("root").appendChild(inputEl);
}
inputEl.type = "file";
inputEl.multiple = true;
inputEl.click();
inputEl.onchange = (e) => { ... }
```